# Gatling - How to use feeder in a post body which is using raw XML file

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I need to use a raw xml file as body in one of my gatling script. in this how we can try feeder.

Tried including variable name in raw file. including feeder in scala code. this didn't worked.

this is the code in scala

```
val feeder = csv("data.csv")

val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
        .feed(feeder)
        .during(10 seconds)
        {
        exec(http("request_0")
            .post("/MED/01_WS/phoenixxm.asmx")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .body(RawFileBody("RecordedSimulation_0000_request.txt")))
            .pause(200.milliseconds)
        }
```

How we can do parametrization in rawfilebody implimentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have Gatling expressions in the file and have them resolved on sending, you need to use 'ELFileBody' instead of 'RawFileBody'